# VSTS - Build a Docker Image

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I have a .NET Core repo in VSTS. I'm trying to create a Build pipeline that builds a Docker image and adds it to my Azure Container Registry. My Build pipeline has a Docker task. This task has the "Build an image" action selected. This action relies on my Dockerfile, which looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.2-runtime-nanoserver-1803

# Install .NET Core
ENV DOTNET_VERSION 2.1.2
```

When my Build pipeline runs, I get an error that says:

```
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\82aba535faccd8bf0e5ce3c122247672fa671214000a12c5481972212c5e2ca0\UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified.
##[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code: 1
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: what agent you are using? this error suggests there is no docker on the agent

Comment: What agent are you using? A private agent, or the hosted agent? If the hosted agent, which one?

Comment: @DanielMann Hosted agent on VSTS Online.

Comment: @ZachTempleton **Which** hosted agent? There are multiple.

Comment: @DanielMann "Hosted VS2017". Is that what you need? I'm sorry, I'm not a VSTS expert. I just setup a basic automated build using the defaults. For that reason, I'm not sure where to get the hosted agent name.

Comment: @ZachTempleton Did you try to build the same project in your local docker? Is that works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the same issue with this one : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6510

Seems it still have some issues with nanoserver-1803

Just try to [setup and host a custom agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) on Azure VM, then check it again.

> https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6510#issuecomment-370152300
>
> I found maybe an explication about this error: VSTS agents seem not
>   support nanoserver-1709 actually. Maybe this will change with the next
>   version 1803.
>
> See details here: [Microsoft/vsts-agent#1393](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1393)
>
> When I setup and host a custom agent on a machine on Azure, it's
>   working. So it's not a bug with this task. I close this issue. Thanks!